# unable to fill listbox from datatable (AutoComplete TextBox)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ado.net, listbox, datatable

I am new to ASP.NET, I am making a search box in my application Using AJAX.

For example: if a user enters "abc" in the textbox, then the textbox will fetch data from the database which starts with "abc".

and then i want to display all the string which starts with `abc` in listBox, i am fetching data in datatable, and data is coming properly in datatable,

**How to fill my ListBox from Datatable ?**

Here is my code Snippet,

**code in SecrchBox.aspx**
`onkeyup i am calling this getdata()`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="SearchBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function getdata() {

            var TextBox1 = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
            var ltrSearchResults = document.getElementById("<%= ltrSearchResults.ClientID %>");
            var str = TextBox1.value;
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length == 0) {
                ltrSearchResults.innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "Newpage.aspx?q=" + str, false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            ltrSearchResults.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            return false;

        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" ></asp:Label><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**code in Newspage,aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Newpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ConnectionString = "Data Source=ilsql;Initial Catalog=krunal_DB;User ID=krunaldbuser;Password=krunal@2012;";
    string[] symbol=new string[2170];

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();           
        }
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["q"] != null)
        {
            string Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["q"]);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
           // string str;

            if (Value.Length > 0)
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                cn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Scrip FROM dbo.SearchBoxData where Scrip Like '%" + Value + "%'", cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                cn.Close();

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {                        
                        str.Append(Convert.ToString(dr["Scrip"]) + "<br>");
                    }

                    str = str.Remove(str.Length - 2, 2);
                }

                Response.Write(str.ToString());

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("No Result Found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Any Help Will Be Appriciated !!***

**Thanks In Advance.**

Comment: use webmethod for this. use this link: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Pass-Additional-Parameter-to-WebMethod-using-ContextKey.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using AutoCompleteExtender from AjaxControlToolkit. Its easier to implement and has been tested well. 
Here is the link with description and code:
[AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

Check the following link for a tutorial to use [AutoCompleteExtender with Database](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/using-autocompleteextender-with-results-from-database.aspx)

Check this code project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit)

Comment: i cant use Dropdown and toolkit i have to use textbox.. it's requirment.

Comment: oh use AutoCompleteTextbox, from the same toolkit, Also update your question title